# Variable with Var and without Var in Function

Tags: javascript, scope

Local variable `oopsGlobal`, gives an error when used outside of function `fun1` but the other variable `name` defined in the same way does not give an error and is accessible outside of the function?

Am I missing something here?

```js
function functionName() {
  // variables created without Var always global scope
  var name = "sudeep";
  console.log("myfirst function");
}

function functionName1() {
  // variables created without Var always global scope
  console.log("Local variable with var:" + name);
}
// Declare your variable here
var myGlobal = 10;

function fun1() {
  // Assign 5 to oopsGlobal Here
  var oopsGlobal = 5; //local scope to variable when accessed outside gives error so working fine
}

functionName();
functionName1();
console.log(name); // **does not give error at all**
fun1();
console.log(name); //**does not give error at all**
console.log(oopsGlobal); //give error so works fine
```

[image]

Comment: The only difference is that [`name` already is a global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

Comment: @Bergi, you gave a link to the `name` property of `Window`, what does this have to do with the variable `name`?

Comment: Thanks Bergi, that is what i was looking for but i do not know exactly why it is referring to window objectsname property. Does that means that we cannot define a local variable in JS with variable named "name", strange to me and if referring window.name property how does it prints my name in console when referring to "name" variable? Here i wanted to create a local variable with "name" in function with var so that no other function can use this variable outside of function.

Comment: @Ivan A property on the global object acts as a global variable - it's like `var name;` in the global scope and therefore affecting assignment to the "undeclared" identifier `name`.

Comment: Just verified and yes it is referring to window.name property. Is there a way to create local variable in a function named "name" and does not refer to window.name?